# Counting a string to ensure the input is within a min/max boundary

Tags: c#

For a part of my project, I want to enforce the rule that the user input can only be within a min/max word boundary. With a minimum of 1 word, and a maximum of 50 words. The boolean isn't changing from the default set value of false. Here is my code:

```
 bool WordCount_Bool = false;

        //Goto the method that handles the calculation of whether the users input is within the boundary.
        WordCount_EH(WordCount_Bool);
        //Decide whether to continue with the program depending on the users input.
        if (WordCount_Bool == true)
        {
            /*TEMP*/MessageBox.Show("Valid input");/*TEMP*/
            /*Split(split_text);*/
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please keep witin the Min-Max word count margin.", "Error - Outside Word Limit boundary");
        }
```

Method handling the array and the change of the boolean:

```
private bool WordCount_EH(bool WordCount_Bool)
    {
        string[] TEMPWordCount_Array = input_box.Text.Split(' ');
        int j = 0;
        int wordcount = 0;
        for (int i = 100; i <=0; i--)
        { 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TEMPWordCount_Array[j]))
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                wordcount++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        if (wordcount >= 1)
        {
            WordCount_Bool = true;
        }
        if (wordcount < 1)
        {
            WordCount_Bool = false;
        }
        return WordCount_Bool;
    }
```

Thank you all in advance.

- Side note: I realize that the for loop will throw an exception or at least is not optimal for its purpose so any advice will be much appreciated.
- Extra Side note: Sorry I should have said that the reason i haven't used length is that wherever possible I should do my own code instead of using built-in functions.

Comment: Note: the `visual-studio` family of tags should only be used when your question is *about* Visual Studio.  "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality, not just a question regarding your code. "

Comment: You need to pass `WordCount_Bool` by `ref` if you want to change it in `WordCount_EH` although in this case you might as well just use the return value.

Comment: I might be  missing something but why not just use the length of TEMPWordCount_Array

Comment: I have to do everything manually for my project, I cant use too many built-in ...Functions?...

Comment: That doesn't exactly reflect real world programming, but if that is the case I'd argue that if using .Length is cheating so is using split(' ')

Comment: This question is probably a bit too broad for SO. The not returning of the boolean/using `ref` isn't the only problem. You have a loop that is never going to run, plus some things that don't really make sense. (Why are you using an extra counter when your loop already has one? Why are you looping backwards? Why using an empty if instead of using logical not?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you should just return a true or false value from your WordCount_EH method like others have said

But just to clear up why it doesn't work. C# by default passes arguments by value. With Value types such as Boolean the actual value of true or false is stored in the variable. So when you pass your Boolean value into your method all you are doing is saying please put this bool value into my new variable (the method parameter). When you make changes to that new variable it only changes that variable. It has no relation to the variable that it was copied from. This is why you don't see a change in original bool variable. You may have named the variables the same but they are infact two different variables.

Jon Skeet explains it fantastically here http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive answer. The problem still isn't fixed, however, I suspect it is more likely to be due to the loop. After reading your answer I read into it further and experimented and now understand the difference between passing by value and passing by reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this should solve it:

```
if(input_box.Text.Split(' ').Length>50)
     return false;
else
     return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `WordCount_Bool` by `ref` if you want to change it in `WordCount_EH`:

```
private bool WordCount_EH(ref bool WordCount_Bool) { ... }

bool WordCount_Bool = false;
WordCount_EH(ref WordCount_Bool);
```

although in this case you might as well use the return value:

```
bool WordCount_Bool = false;
WordCount_Bool = WordCount_EH(WordCount_Bool);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass argument by reference, you need to do as per @Lee suggestion.

For your logic implementation, you can use following code to avoid array indexing.

```
 // It would return true if you word count is greater than 0 and less or equal to 50
 private bool WordCount_EH()
 {
      var splittedWords = input_box.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
      return (splittedWords.Count > 0 && splittedWords.Count <= 50);
 }
```